# Azure Devops build fails not finding 3rd party reference. Error: CS0246

Tags: .net, azure-devops

I'm attempting to have my solution built in Azure Devops Pipelines. However, the build always fails as it fails to find packages which are indeed NuGet packages.

I have excerpts from the Azure pipeline build which details the packages being successfully added and yet the build consistently fails to find them and reports back that a reference is missing.

Previously, these packages were actually .dll files which were added as references to the solution but I have changed them to becoming NuGet packages instead. I was hoping that but doing this, the solution would become deployable from Azure.

The references in the code where the build is failing are as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ADK.PostScript.Images;
using ADK.Printers;
using APWebGrabber;
using EO.Pdf; //error
```

Another file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Memcached.ClientLibrary; //error
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace VanillaBlue.Core.Cache
{
    public class VbMemcachHelper
    {
        private static readonly MemcachedClient mclient; //error
```

After including these are NuGet packages I would expected these references to resolve but unfortunately this has not occurred. Any help in this regard would be appreciated!

Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you use your own build agent machine to reproduce this issue? That can give you a local environment to investigate what's up.

Comment: Can you share your `.csproj`?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Devops build fails not finding 3rd party reference. Error: CS0246

If you can build the solution successfully on your local, but failed on the Azure Devops. You may need to add nuget tasks to restore the package:

[NuGet Tool Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops)

[Restore NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops#restore-nuget-packages)

When we build the project/solution on local machine, the packages is downloaded stored in the \packages folder, this folder is ignored by the source control when we submit our source code(This is recommended.), so when we build the project/solution on the Azure DevOps, we need add nuget restore task to restore nuget package before we build it:

[image]

[image]

Note: If you already use the nuget restore task and it executed successfully, please try to check if you have add the `\packages` folder in to the source control, if yes, move it out.

Hope this helps.